# How do I use rust quote library for a procedural macro that generates a new struct type

Tags: rust, rust-proc-macros

I have a struct like this:

```
struct Input {
   key1: u32,
   key2: String,
   value1: u16,
   value2: u8
}
```

I want to write a proc macro using `quote` that generates this struct:

```
struct InputKey {
    key1: u32,
    key2: String,
}
```

How do I do this?

The most I could figure out is this:

```
let ident_key_type = quote::format_ident!("{}Key", ident);
quote! {
    pub struct #ident_key_type {
    }
}
```

This is creating an empty struct.

I am unable to figure out how to write a for-loop to iterate over the 2 key fields "Key1" and "key2" and add those 2 fields to the InputKey struct.

My code uses the `quote` library so I would prefer a solution that uses that.

Comment: Have you seen the readme on [Repetition](https://crates.io/crates/quote#repetition)? You'd have to create a vec/iterator that contains `quote!{ keyN: typN, }` as elements for that.

Comment: Are there always `key1: u32` and `key2: String`? Or could it be `n` key fields of any type `T`?